# DataContractSerializer

Tags: .net, datacontractserializer

I have the following class

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "VersionRange")]
    public sealed class VersionRange
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Lower")]
        private readonly Version _lower;

        [DataMember(Name = "Upper")]
        private readonly Version _upper;

        public VersionRange(Version lower, Version upper)
        {
            _lower = lower;
            _upper = upper;
        }
    }
```

and I want it to **de** serialize from the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VersionRange>
    <Lower>1.2.3.4</Lower>
    <Upper>5.6.7.8</Upper>
</VersionRange>
```

I've tried to archive this by implementing IDataContractSurrogate but did not succeed at all. Whe I return `typeof(string)` for `typeof(Version)` in `GetDataContractType` method deserialization fails and GetDeserializedObject method is not called.

So, Is there any chance to use standard Version class and get it deserialized from `"a.b.c.d"` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to deserialize to a string property and then in the `set` method for the property convert the value to a Version.

```
[DataMember(Name = "Lower")]
private string _lowerStr
{
    set
    {
        _lower = new Version(value);
    }
}

private Version _lower;

/// and the same for Upper.
```

I have seen this commonly used for parsing datetime values which might be supplied with obscure formatting

Comment: in addition, if your `private Version _lower` must remain `readonly` then you can still set it using reflection in the `_lowerStr_set` method.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are reading wrong XML. Correct XML should be something like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<VersionRange xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Lower xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
    <d2p1:_Build>1</d2p1:_Build>
    <d2p1:_Major>12</d2p1:_Major>
    <d2p1:_Minor>1</d2p1:_Minor>
    <d2p1:_Revision>3</d2p1:_Revision>
  </Lower>
  <Upper xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
    <d2p1:_Build>1</d2p1:_Build>
    <d2p1:_Major>12</d2p1:_Major>
    <d2p1:_Minor>1</d2p1:_Minor>
    <d2p1:_Revision>3</d2p1:_Revision>
  </Upper>
</VersionRange>
```